# Loading commands from file

Tags: terminal

Is it possible to write commands to text file and then loaded it into terminal as file? If yes, how is the command for loading the file? Thank you.

For instance file_commands:

```
awk -f program.awk d01.active > out1
awk -f program.awk d02.active > out2
```

It is because of a problem with running an awk program that doesn't work with command

```
awk -f program.awk d??.active > out
```

I need to use program.awk for lots of files and this seemed to me as easier solution when I am not able to repair program for that command with ??.

It is related with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55313187/more-input-files-in-awk?noredirect=1#comment97356807_55313187

Comment: Isn't this what an ordinary script is? Could you possibly give an example of what it is you want to do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have a file with a list of shell commands, one per line, then you have a shell script! All you need to do is run it:

```
sh file_commands
```

However, that isn't the simplest approach for what I think you need. If you want to run `program.awk` on each `d??.active` file in the current directory, you can simply use a loop:

```
for file in d??.active; do awk -f program.awk "$file" > "$file".out; done
```

That will create a `d01.active.out` out file for `d01.active`, a `d02.active.out` file for `d02.active` and so on.

Answer (score 5):

A shell script is essentially a list of commands terminated by line separators that will be interpreted as a list of commands by the specified (or default) interpreter.

To specify an interpreter your file should start with a [hashbang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) (also called shebang).

Examples:

```
#!/bin/sh
#!/bin/bash
#!/bin/ksh
#!/bin/zsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

Note: each of these interpreters have their own syntax and set of rules.  You should study the manual for whichever one you plan on using.

---

After your hashbang you can essentially just start listing your commands to be executed each on their own line.

Note: these commands will be executed in order from top to bottom

---

In your example you would want something like:

```
#!/bin/sh

awk -f program.awk d01.active > out1
awk -f program.awk d02.active > out2
```

You would then have to make this file executable and would run it by specifying the full or relative path to the file on the command line.  (or by running `sh /path/to/file`)

---

This does seem like a potential x-y problem though and can probably be handled in a more programmatic way.

Such as:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in d??.active; do
    n=${file:1:2}
    awk -f program.awk "$file" > "out$n"
done
```